# How can I track a bug fix for Safari?

Tags: macos, safari, local-storage, bug

We have been seeing an issue on Safari, starting with Safari 14.1 (macOS 11.3), where local storage was not synchronised across tabs (more info: https://twitter.com/jaffathecake/status/1389493762129375232 ). It was not fixed in the recent macOS release — 11.4 — either. How can we track such bugs? How can we know which future release is tracking this update?

I have tried Feedback Assistant and Apple Communities already. Any other suggestions?

**Background:**
Copied from tweet: Tabs end up with separate localStorage for reading, but the same localStorage for writing. This will likely result in data loss for users. [More info here](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=225344). Also, any cross-tab communication that relies on the 'storage' event [Demo](https://t.co/RsrbcSm9UI?amp=1)

Comment: Can you include the details from the tweet? It doesn't appear to be working.

Comment: @Burgi Copied from tweet: Tabs end up with separate localStorage for reading, but the same localStorage for writing. This will likely result in data loss for users. Bug: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=225344. Also, any cross-tab communication that relies on the 'storage' event (Demo: https://t.co/RsrbcSm9UI?amp=1).

Comment: You should add that to your post. If the tweet is ever deleted, future people will not be able to understand the context. Please see [ask] and take our [tour].

Comment: You cannot. Apple software development is not public. Not even WebKit.